# Number extends Module and when in Module's Extended Method

Tags: ruby, ruby-1.9.3

When an instance of an object extends a module and `extended` is called on the module does the `base` already extend module?

```
module M
  def self.extended base
    # when this is called has base extended
  end

  def self.some_method
    # that does something special ;)
  end
end

obj = Object.new
obj.extend M
```

**Update:** Okay, so an Object and a String works, but why doesn't numbers work? I get `TypeError: can't define singleton`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot define a singleton on a Fixnum in ruby, because there is really only one of them (for each Fixnum). For example (in IRB):

```
1.object_id
=> 3
1.object_id
=>3
```

Unlike strings, for example:

```
"panda".object_id
=> 78405050
"panda".object_id
=> 78383110
```

Obviously the specific numbers are going to vary on your system.

This makes sense, since there is no way for a particular "instance" of 73 to be different from any other "instance" of 73 (and I use the word "instance" loosely because it isn't really an instance - they are all the same object).

http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Fixnum.html

Comment: so what if there's only one of the number `1`, why can't i define a singleton method on this to give it specialized behaviour different to the number `2` for example? :) Fixnums *do* have their own ivars and i see no reason why they couldn't also have their own singleton classes :)

Answer (score 0):

Yup!

```
[1] pry(main)> module Foo
[1] pry(main)*   def hi
[1] pry(main)*   end  
[1] pry(main)*   def self.extended(base)
[1] pry(main)*     base.hi
[1] pry(main)*   end  
[1] pry(main)* end  
=> nil
[2] pry(main)> s = ""
=> ""
[3] pry(main)> s.extend(Foo)
=> ""
[4] pry(main)> quit
```